# SharePoint 2010: form based authentication using HttpModules

Tags: sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

We have a single-sign on authentication server for our web-farm applications. With below two changes, we make our web applications use single sign on authentication server:

1. Add the dlls of authentication module in bin (or GAC).
2. Change web.config to refer that module:

2.a

```
<authentication mode="Forms">      <forms ..... enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="" requireSSL="false">      </forms>
```

2.b

```
<httpModule><add name="authenticationModule"...../>
```

Now we want to use SharePoint in one of these applications. And user should be able to access SP2010 GUI without logging in again.
When I tried making these two changes in SharePoint website's web.config, this is what happened:

1. URL got redirected to SSO server's login page.
2. When I gave credentials, I got following plaing text on the screen.
   500 Internal server error.
3. This error didn't get logged anywhere, neither in SP logs nor in windows (Event Viewer).

Is SP capable of authenticating with such custom authentication module?
If yes, what are the changes required?
Thanks in advance.